# How to Validate Collection of Times?

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-applications

I'd like to validate submitted collection of time strings both on the client and server side with javascript/coffeescript and ruby respectively. Upon validation the time values will be stored to the DB. Suggestions on how best to accomplish this are appreciated. Thanks.

I would like to validate:

1. The entered time is realizable
2. The time periods in the collection do NOT overlap.

Following is an example set of user submitted data:

```
[{"start": "10:00 AM", "end": "11:30 AM"}, 
 {"start": "11:30 AM", "end": "1:00 PM"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Ruby:**

You'll need a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations):

1. You can try to instantiate your start/end into Date.new, if you can't, it's not valid.
2. If you can instatiante, you can validate if start_date <= end_date.